# Is there any difference between fascia and skin ?Are both the different names of the same thing?

Tags: skin

Skin is the outermost layer of the body ,and it consists of two layers; epidermis and the second layer the dermis .There is another layer the (third layer) beneath the dermis called superficial fascia or subcutaneous tissue. I want to know that is superficial facia  a part of skin.?Can we say that fascia is another name of skin?

Answer (score 5):

The superficial fascia is the lowermost layer of the skin found in nearly all parts of the body and it usually blends with the reticular region of the dermis. But that doesn't mean it's a part of the dermis. The subcutaneous tissue/hypodermis/superficial fascia is NOT part of the skin but lies beneath the  dermis of the skin. Therefore, it can't be used as an alternative name for the skin.

Answer (score 0):

Fascia is made up of sheets of connective tissue located below the cutaneous layer. These fibrous tissues attach, stabilize & separate muscles, maintain vessel patency, and enclose different organs.

[Fascia can be classified](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK526038/) as superficial, deep, visceral, or parietal.

Superficial: Superficial fascia is found directly under the skin and superficial adipose tissue layers. It can sometimes include muscle fibers; for example: platysma muscle in the neck, the external anal sphincter, and the dartos fascia in the scrotum.

Deep: This one surrounds bones, muscles, nerves, and blood vessels. It is commonly has a more fibrous consistency and rich in hyaluronan as compared to the other subtypes. Deep fascia tends to be highly vascularized and contains well developed lymphatics. It is further divided into 2 subtypes:

- Aponeurotic fascia
  It forms into sheets of pearly-white fibrous tissue to attach muscles needing a wide area of attachment. Aponeurosis can thin into a tendon and become a point of origin or insertion for other muscles. [Some examples](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23855010/) of aponeurotic fascia include the fascia of the face, limbs, thoracolumbar fascia, and rectus sheath.
- Epimysial fascia
  Also known as the epimysium, this is the connective tissue sheath surrounding skeletal muscle and can, in some cases, connect directly to the periosteum of bones.

Visceral: Visceral fascia surrounds organs in cavities like the abdomen, lung (pleura), and heart (pericardium).

Parietal: [Parietal fascia](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22196430/) is a general term for tissues that line the wall of a body cavity just outside of the parietal layer of serosa. The most commonly known parietal fascia is found in the pelvis.